# Android - How to convert uri data into Intent format

Tags: android

**Store the Intent data and result code:**

```
public static int resultCode;
public static Intent resultData;
editor1.putString("data123", String.valueOf(resultData));
editor1.putInt("code", resultCode);
editor1.apply();
```

**Get the stored value in broadcast receiver when boot completed.**

```
private Intent telApp;
String  result_Data = sharedPreferences.getString("data123", " ");
int code=sharedPreferences.getInt("code",0);

try {
  telApp = Intent.parseUri(result_Data, 0);
  Log.e("data...", String.valueOf(telApp));
   Uri uri=telApp.getData(); // get data using uri. But this value is get in uri form.
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I stored the intent data and result code from onActivityResult() method using sharedpreferneces.I get that values in broadcast receiver when boot completed.

Here I get the **result_data** string value which is stored in `OnActivityResult()` method.That data is converted in uri form and I get the intent using  this method.

```
telApp = Intent.parseUri(result_Data, 0);
```

Here I get inetnt action and intent data both. But I want only intent data so I used `and I get the intent data in uri form. Now I want to store that value as intent. So how can I store/convert  uri value in a intent format?

**Edit:1**

I edit my code and uri is define in this code.

> Uri uri=telApp.getData();

`

Comment: A pretty unreadable post. Unclear what you want. If you want to convert uri data to something than you should have started with your uri. I do not see an uri.

Comment: @greenapps, I edit my code please check it Edit:1.Its stored the uri value.

Comment: Thad is bad info! How should we know where that telApp comes from or even what it is? And further you do nothing with `uri`.